# jquery: get mouse click if inside a div or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

i have this HTML page

```
<html>
<body>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div id='in_or_out'>e</div>
<div>f</div>
</body>
</html>
```

a,b,c,d,e and f could be divs also not just a plain text.

I want to get the mouse click event, but how could i know if it's inside or outside #in_or_out div ?

EDIT :: guys, i know how to check if the div is click or not, but i want my event to be fired when the click is outside that div

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to negate a selector, like: 'give me all divs where id is unlike xy'. You would need to fire the event and then handle the exclusion within the function..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$("body > div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "in_or_out") {
        // inside
    } else {
        // not inside
    }
});
```

EDIT: just learned, that there is a negate:

```
$("body > div:not(#in_or_out)").click(function(e) {
    // not inside
});
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to detect whether or not you've clicked inside or outside the div, set the event handler on the `documentElement` and let it propagate from the other elements upwards:

```
$("html").click(function (e)
{
    if (e.target == document.getElementById("in_or_out"))
        alert("In");
    else
        alert("Out!");
});
```

Comment: This will not work if div (#in_or_out) contains other elements and the user clicks on inside element. Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/opd3ktdf/4/

Comment: @avi, nope, neither will the accepted answer.  For that you could do something like `.contains(e.target)` — https://jsfiddle.net/opd3ktdf/6/

Comment: Yes, that will work, I was not showing the right answer in the Fiddle. Just explaining the use of your answered code.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this one will help you

```
$('body').click(function(){
    //do smth
});
$('div#in_or_out').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do smth else
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends what you want. If you only want to execute code, when it was **inside** `#in_or_out`, you can do:

```
$('#in_or_out').click(function(){ /* your code here */ });
```

You can have a status variable that says whether the mouse is in `#in_or_out` or not:

```
var inside = false;

$('#in_or_out').hover(function() { inside = true; }, function() { inside = false; });
```

Then whenever a click occurs you can check with `inside` whether the click was inside `in_or_out` or not.

Reference: [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

**Update:**

No matter to which element you bind the `click` handler, you can always do this:

```
$('element').click(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('id') !== 'in_or_not') {

     }
 });
```

Comment: Just remember `in` is a keyword in javascript and not allowed as a variable name ;-)

Comment: @Ande E: Yes, I noticed it, I changed it ;) Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

for inside it would be

```
$("#in_or_out").click(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

for outside...I've got no idea.

**Edit:** You could try to do the same for body-tag (assigning a click-handler to the document itself). But I'm not sure if both events would fire by that.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$("#in_or_out").click(function() {
    alert("IN DIV!");
});
```