# Attempting a mousedown when mouseout

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to create an event specifically for a drop down menu I'm creating. Where if it's visible `.is(":visible")`, anywhere clicked but the menu itself, will close it.

--- EDIT ---

This is what didn't work. The other code worked fine. And `.on()` is working perfectly, but the following code isn't giving me what I want.

```
$(document).on("mouseout", "#menuPopUp", function(){
   $(document).on("mousedown", function(){
      $("#menuPopUp").hide();
   });
});
```

I'm trying to hide `#menuPopUp` when anything but itself is clicked.

Comment: Please post some html also or just [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it..

Comment: Edited. Read what I have, I think the way I phrased my question might have caused confusion.

Comment: this could be what you need.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265297/jquery-get-mouse-click-if-inside-a-div-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way: **http://jsfiddle.net/tTkAB/1/**

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "#headerPicMenu", function() {
    if ($("#menuPopUp").is(":visible")) {
       $("#menuPopUp").hide();
    } else {
       $("#menuPopUp").show();
    }
});

$(document).on("mouseout", "#menuPopUp", function() {
    if ($("#menuPopUp").is(":visible")) {
       $("#menuPopUp").hide();
    } else {
       $("#menuPopUp").show();
    }
});

$("#menuPopUp").on('mousedown', function() {
   $(this).mousedown();
});
```

Updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: you can use your if conditions in place of alert.

Comment: How? I've done the `$(document).on("mousedown", function(){});` before and it didn't work. And mind you, I said I wanted the box to disappear when anything but the popup menu is clicked.

Comment: Updated the answer. Is this what you want? or it would be nice if you make a fiddle for it. That would be more useful to see your situation of code.

Comment: Partially, I want it to disappear if anything is clicked but `#menuPopUp`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding/removing a class on mouseover/mouseout and then testing for it in the click event; something along these lines:

```
$("#menuPopUp").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).addClass("menuover"); 
});

$("#menuPopUp").mouseout(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("menuover"); 
});

$(document).on("mousedown", function(){
    if($("#menuPopUp").is(":visible") && !$("#menuPopUp").hasClass("menuover")) {
        $("#menuPopUp").hide();
    }
});
```

​

Comment: I have, it's just for some reason the click isn't registering probably because I'm doing something wrong.